# converting JSON object to JS Key/value pairs Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, jsonp

I have a requirement, where i am having a JSON object which should be converted to Key/value pairs array.

JSON:

```
Object {id: "1213115", transac_status: "Y", trans_id: "601427"....}
```

This should be converted to JS array like below:
JS Array:

```
var transData = [{ id: "1213115", transac_status: "Y", trans_id: 601427".... ];
```

I tried the below script for the conversion.

```
var transData = $.map(Object , function (e2, e1) {
    return [[e2, e1]];
});
```

The array has not been converted as expected, Instead it has the following :-

```
Array[2]
, 
Array[2]
, 
Array[2]
, 
Array[2]
```

..... etc

Comment: You want the whole `object` to be contained inside an `array`? or create an `array` for every key/value?

Comment: This is somewhat confusing, your example seems like just `var transData = [Object]` ?

Comment: @Moin : I want the whole object to be converted as a single array. Not every kery/value as a array.

Comment: Okay. So have you tried doing it like: `var obj = [{id: "1213115", transac_status: "Y", trans_id: "601427"}];`
Means containing it in square brackets?

Comment: Yes @Moin! Sorry for the confusion. I need to convert JSON to the format exactly as you have mentioned above. It should be a key/Value pair (JS Object)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code I think. You said, that you want to produce an array with key-value pairs, which you actually do:

```
Array[2] , Array[2] , Array[2] , Array[2]
```

This is just the output that `console.log` produces. If you look closer at your array you'll see, that it actually is:

```
[["1213115", "id"], ["Y", "transac_status"], ["601427", "trans_id"]]
```

Thinking about it, you probably might want to switch your key/value pair, like this:

```
var transData = $.map(Object , function (value, key) {
    return [[key, value]];
});
```

I renamed the function arguments to make things a little clearer.

Output would be:

```
[["id", "1213115"], ["transac_status", "Y"], ["trans_id, "601427"]]
```

Tipp: If you are working in a browser, you can just output the whole array with this line, which gives you a nice table-form output:

```
console.table(transData);
```

[image]

Is that what you are looking for? Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** Object is a list of objects

```
var arr = [];

$.map(Object, function(item) {
    arr.push(item);
});
```

This will push each object into the array;

[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)