# Javascript / Json convert data format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am reading data from a page which looks like this:

```
{"cars":0,"bikes":"1"}
```

In order to get the charts working in my page I need to convert it to something like this:

```
[{"key":"cars","value":0},{"key":"bikes","value":1}]
```

What would be the best way to convert this data, as this data can increase in size.

Comment: This operation can be described as: "turning an object/dictionary into an array/sequence of key-value pairs". It can be done in a number of ways, the most C-forward is with a for..in (over the keys in the object) and Array.push.

Comment: Examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627889/converting-json-name-value-to-array-with-object-literals?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240678/converting-json-object-to-js-key-value-pairs-array?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615669/convert-objects-properties-and-values-to-array-of-key-value-pairs (except don't build a string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` and `Object.keys()` to do this

```js
var obj = {"cars":0,"bikes":"1"};
var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(e) {
  return {key: e, value: obj[e]}
});

console.log(result)
```